# vmware horizon client : how to copy paste from vm to host client?

Tags: vmware, vmware-horizon

I see clipboard for copy/pasting from host client machine to VM works but not vice versa. Is there a way to move things such as text or entire files from the VM to the host client? Can a drive from the host client be mounted as an alternative to using the clipboard to move something from the VM to the host?

Comment: Most VM Hypervisor have a plugin you install to the VM that allow passing data between the two. What research have you done?

Comment: As said, it works one way (host to vm) and althought there is a "sharing" functionality in the vmware player where you can specify folders on the host machine that should be mapped on the VM once in the VM \\tsclient is not accessible just as descrived here https://communities.vmware.com/thread/591152. It is probably some security policy that is preventing bringing out of the VM so to say anything .

Answer (score 0):

Regargin copy and paste of files and clipboard content, it looks like the the one way behavior is a default.

[The VMware Horizon Client docs](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Windows/2103/horizon-client-windows-installation/GUID-37D7DE28-8327-4A4A-B265-22943AC69A94.html) state:

> You can also copy and paste files and folders from a remote desktop or published application to the client system if a Horizon administrator enables these features.